# how to select elements that contains a call and not another in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ilets assume i have the following HTML

```
<a class='x y'>A</a>
<a class='x '>B</a>
<a class='x '>C</a>
<a class='x y'>D</a>
```

how can I select all `<a>` that have class `x => jQuery('a.x')` and not class `y` without iterating with a loop to exclude them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector, or the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
var elems = $("a.x:not(.y)");

//or

var elems = $("a.x").not(".y");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CcpeC/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var e = $("a.x").not(".y");
```

or

```
 var e = $("a.x").filter(function(){

        return !$(this).hasClass("y");
  });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6J5Rf/)